# How to check user are logged correctly in firebase swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have issue, even when i put wrong password, my app showing me info about Success login, but in reality im not. How to make work it properly?

```
Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: userEmail, completion: {
            (providers, error) in

            if error != nil {
                self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Unhandled error", alertMessage: "Undefined error #SignUpViewController_0001");
                return;
            } else if providers == nil {
                self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: "This account is not exist.");
                return;
            }
        })

        // Login

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            guard self != nil else {
                self?.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Alert", alertMessage: "Wrong password.");
                return }
        }

        self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Success", alertMessage: "You are successfuly sign in.", dismiss: true);

        // Return to initial view
```

Answer (score 0):

`Auth.auth().signIn()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback you pass will be invoked some time later with the results of the sign in.  What your code is doing is immediately calling `self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Success",...)` before the sign in is complete.  You should only expect sign in results inside the callback, not on the next line of code after you call `signIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

This function I wrote for my current application.

```
func loginButtonTapped() {
    indicator.setupIndicatorView(view, containerColor: .white, indicatorColor: .CustomGreen())
    view.alpha = 0.7
    let email = mainView.userEmail
    let password = mainView.userPassword
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified == true {
                self.view.alpha = 1.0
                self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
                print("Logined")
            } else {
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.view.alpha = 1.0
                        self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
                        Alert.showAlert(title: "Warning", subtitle: "You have not activate your account yet. We have sent you an email to activate it.", leftView: UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "isWarningIcon")), style: .warning)
                    } else {
                        self.view.alpha = 1.0
                        self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
                        Alert.showAlert(title: "Error", subtitle: "Incorrect email.", leftView: UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "isErrorIcon")), style: .danger)
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
            Alert.showAlert(title: "Error", subtitle: "Incorrect email or password.", leftView: UIImageView(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier.error)!, style: .danger)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Doug mentioned in his answer, Firebase is asynchronous and data is only valid within the closure following the function call. It takes time for that data to become valid so any code outside the function call following the closure will be called before the code inside the closure.

So what that means for your code is

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { [weak self] authResult, error in
     //this code will execute *after* the code that displays success
}

//this code will execute *before* the code within the closure following the signIn 
self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "Success"
```

Here's some sample code that handles errors and provides the proper sequence for code flow.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pw, completion: { (auth, error) in
    if let x = error {
        let err = x as NSError
        switch err.code {
        case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
            print("wrong password")
        case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
            print("invalued email")
        case AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue:
            print("accountExistsWithDifferentCredential")
        default:
            print("unknown error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        if let _ = auth?.user {
            print("authd") //user is auth'd proceed to next step
        } else {
            print("authentication failed - no auth'd user")
        }
    }
})
```